# how to disable given permissions in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to find a way to un-allow a permissions I previously allowed in chrome. specifically the file system permission.

Here is how the popup looks like

[image]

I have tried the "permissions" menu in "settings" but could not find this specific permission.

I need chrome to prompt me again for this permission next time I visit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles here...

[Chrome settings] -> [Content settings] -> [Cookies] -> [See all cookies and site data]

Or directly

chrome://settings/siteData

Look for *File system*

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

[Change website permissions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6148059?hl=en)

In case that link disappears, it says that you can:

1. go to the site
2. click on the icon next to the left of the URL (a lock icon?)
3. change the permissions for specific actions, like Automatic Downloads.

Not sure if that's the same as "Store files on this device" but give it a try.

Comment: so I didn't find "store files on this device" permission. where can I find it?